# NRF24L01+ Issues antenna

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, nrf24l01+, relay

I have 2x NRF24L01+ communicating but they are unreliable. It doesn't matter if they are right night to each other or 100ft away. For some odd reason when I place my hand on the antenna it work perfectly. Why would this be? 
I have one set up to send and one to receive. All I am sending from one to the other is a 3 digit number to turn on a relay.

Comment: Are they the modules with the power amp and SMA antenna, or the ones without the amplifier and PCB track or ceramic antenna?

Comment: And how well do they work if they are 20' away from each other? Too close and it will distort the signal. Too distant and the signal will be too weak.

Comment: Yes they are SMA. Here is what I bought [link](https://www.amazon.com/Makerfocus-Wireless-NRF24L01-Antistatic-Compatible/dp/B01IK78PQA/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1494886781&sr=8-3&keywords=nrf24l01) . About 30' away was my test and still the same issue. I found when I remove the antenna is works much better.

Comment: Those ones don't work well when too close together. The signal is too strong and distorts. You may be attenuating it with your hand making it work better. It should be good over 100' though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. As the signals where too close I found where I could tone down the signal strength using:

```
   radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
```

Because I didn't want to loose long range capabilities too I send my packet out 4 times at this lower signal and then increase the strength back to max to send out another 4 packets. This way my close range and far range relay will receive the signal.